# How can I read/write a value in a shared memory using two programs(one in C and the other in C#)

Tags: c#

Can someone help me with some info and some code example if it's possible?
I need to read/write a value in a shared memory using two programs(one in C and the other in C#). I have to use a buffer in which I write the value. Also that buffer is a struct.

The Client should be written in C# and the server in C.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need this?  Why do you need one in C and one in C#?  What have you tried?  We aren't going to do your work for you, we'll only help you.

Comment: Thats possible if one app knows memory address of other app. But I don't know how. Waiting someone :P

Comment: I have a Server which is wroted in C. I need to communicate with the server using a C# program. I want to write a value in a shared memory with my client in C# and the server should be able to see that value, and based on that value he should answer by calling a function.

Comment: I want to know how to make those two programs to communicate. I tried with Memory Mapped File, also I tried using Windows API functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 solutions:

1. You can use shared memory if two apps are running on the same computer. There are many examples on the web about using shared memory both in C# and C/C++. In C#, shared memory functions are well wrapped in .Net Framework. In C/C++ you may use windows API directly or use a library such as boost.
2. You may use network communication between these processes. If both apps are running on the same computer, you can use up address 127.0.0.1 (localhost) for inter-network communication without need to know ip address. For network communication, again there are many source code examples on the web both for C# and C/C++. You'd better to use TCP sockets, and use a serializer/deserializer such as json, or use your custom format for communication between these processes.
3. If the amount of data and the number of times these apps need to communicate with each other is very low, and the apps are running on the same computer, you can use file-based communication which is very simple, but NOT RECOMMENDED for performance issues. You can define a file on a specific path on the computer, and periodically (say 1 per second) check for file existence. When first app wants to send data to second app, first app creates that file and writes data into it. Second app becomes aware of that file existence, reads its contents and deletes the file. First app waits for the file to be deleted, and then starts for sending another data to the second app by doing the same job. The same can be applied for sending data from second app to the first app. This approach needs only use of file i/o functions!

Comment: Could the communication between those two apps work If I use Memory Mapped File in my C# program, and on the other one are used Windows Api functions?, because I tried and it didn't worked, I also tried using the Windows API functions on my C# program but again it didn't work. I guess that the main problem is how I make both programs access the same memory.

Comment: Yes, your right, MemoryMappedFile class in .NET is for using shared memory.